# How to perform clustering/grouping on categorical variables based on frequencies?

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis

I have a sample set of observations as follows

```
var1 var2 var3 var4
 1    2    1     1
 3    2    1     3
 1    2    0     1
 3    2    2     3
```

All the values are categorical in nature. I want to group 1st and 3rd row to one cluster and 2nd and 4th to another cluster.I believe One-hot encoding is not effective in this case because categorical variables does not posses any rank and they are purely nominal in nature .

(The rows need not have to be absolutely same as well). Is there a pre-built mathematical algorithm to group these rows based on similarities/frequencies? Can anyone suggest a good way to do it? Or should I go with one-hot coding?

Comment: Also clustering on a categorical data can be performed using the gower distances in partition around medoids algorithm, if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gower distance to calculate the distance between categorical variables.

Below an example:

```
# Import data
dta <- read.table(header = TRUE, textConnection("Var1 var2 var3 var4
 1    2    1     1
 3    2    1     3
 1    2    0     1
 3    2    2     3"))
dta <- as.data.frame(lapply(dta, as.factor))


# Create distance matrix using gower distance using gower package (fast)
# The code below computes the complete distance matrix, while only the upper
# or lower half is needed; so this could be improved. 
library(gower)
pairs <- expand.grid(x = seq_len(nrow(dta)), y = seq_len(nrow(dta)))
dist <- gower_dist(dta[pairs$x,], dta[pairs$y, ])
dist <- array(dist, dim = c(nrow(dta), nrow(dta)))

# Convert matrix to distance object
dist <- as.dist(dist)

# Cluster using distance matrix; for this there are numerous options
# Use hierarchical clustering in this case
cl <- hclust(dist)
plot(cl)
```

Another solution using the cluster package (als contains a large number of
clustering methods)

```
library(cluster)
dist <- daisy(dta, metric = "gower")

cl <- hclust(dist)
plot(cl)
```

In order to derive the clustering from the hierarchical clustering, the tree needs to be 'cut'  into the clusters. This can be done by specifying the height at which the tree needs to be cut, or by specifying the number of clusters. Below I specify the number of clusters:

```
dta$cluster <- cutree(cl, k = 2)
```

Comment: I am new to this approach. Please excuse me if I am asking a wrong question? So, is it possible to add the respective cluster name to each of the rows ? Can you show how to ?

Comment: @EdwinVarghese Added an example, but you should read up on these methods if you want to use them. For example start with chapter 10 of introduction to statistical learning: http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf.